# How to delete data/rows from multiple tables in SQL Server based on some condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a DB that has around 500 tables. I created two table variables to help me with deleting some data:

1. To store `ProductID` values (hundreds) from `MainTable` which are referenced inside 400 other tables in the same DB.
2. To store the names of all tables that contain `ProductID` column (referencing the `MainTable` table), so I can do "foreach" through that list.

Now, how do I tell SQL to delete all data from all the tables in the list that have `ProductID` from the list?

Now I need to delete all the records from `MainTable`, but first of course I need to delete all the data from all other tables that is referencing those `ProductID` values.

Is there a way to create a short query something like:

```sql
DELETE * 
FROM A_LIST_OF_ALL_TABLES_THAT_CONTAIN_PRODUCTID_COLUMN
WHERE ProductID IN A_LIST_OF_ALL_PRODUCTIDs
```

Comment: If your Foreign keys have `CASCADE ON DELETE` enabled, then just delete the rows from the "parent" table. If not, then I would suggest configuring it (if you can, as some designs will conflict with it). Otherwise you'll need to `DELETE` the rows from the "top downwards"; issuing a `DELETE` statement against each table. There is no "quick" way, if you don't have cascading, but then you *should* know your design. if you don;t have foreign keys, you're in for a "world of pain", and i suggest you fix that.

Comment: I am not the admin, and we don't have ``cascade on delete`` enabled, I will see if the team lead can have it turned on at least for this scenario. Thanks

Comment: Yes, don't find hacks when the software already has a way to do it correctly. Cascading deletes of primary keys to foreign tables is exactly the type of referential integrity you should leave the database to do. Speak to the appropriate people to have the database and tables correctly configured.

Answer (score 0):

What i did in the past is to write a Query that generates the 400 Delete-Statements in a script, something like:

```
SELECT 'DELETE FROM ' !! TABLE_NAME !! ' WHERE PRODUCT_ID IN (SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM PRODUCT_ID_TABLE);' FROM TABLE_WITH_TABLE_NAMES
```

and then executed the script.

Comment: Yes, at least that is a solution

Comment: `'DELETE FROM ' !! TABLE_NAME !! ' WHERE...`?A double exclamation mark (`!!`) isn't a "concatenator "in T-SQL.

Comment: You're right, its good old host db2(if I remember it right), but it's the idea that count's ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH LIST_OF_TABLES AS (
    SELECT 'table1' as tablename
    union all
    SELECT 'table2'
    union all
    SELECT 'table3'
), LIST_OF_PRODUCTID AS (
    SELECT 'product1' as product
    union all
    SELECT 'product2'
)
SELECT
   CONCAT('DELETE FROM ',tablename,' WHERE productid=', product,';')
FROM LIST_OF_TABLES
JOIN LIST_OF_PRODUCTID on 1=1
```

output:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE productid=product1;
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE productid=product1;
DELETE FROM table3 WHERE productid=product1;
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE productid=product2;
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE productid=product2;
DELETE FROM table3 WHERE productid=product2;
```

Now you only need to fine-tune this script to fit in your situation, so finally you can run the output as a script on your database...